# Using a file type plugin file (ftplugin) to change the file type in vim / neovim

Tags: vim, markdown, vi, neovim, multimarkdown

To automate a step for creating multimarkdown notes. I'd like for neovim to change the filetype of a file based on the contents of first line. All of my multimarkdown notes begin with `title` E.g.

`title: Euclidean Distance`

Ideally i'd like to keep this out of my init.vim (.vimrc) file, however neovim does not update the buffer upon read/open when I place the following in my `../ftplugin/txt.vim` file.

```
" Change the file type to markdown
if getline(1) =~ '^title:'
   set ft=markdown
endif
```

How can I get neovim to check the first line of the file and change its type or at least change its syntax. Thx.

I understand that the runtime doesn't watch all the files. Is the only way to automatically check the file type and make changes is by using `autocmd` and source the `ftplugin/txt.vim` file via init.vim (.vimrc)

Comment: `title.$` will not match `title: Euclidean Distance`. Maybe you meant: `^title:`

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks for the response the regex you shared does capture the first line of the file. I'll update my question as my main issue is that neovim does not change the file type upon opening/reading a new buffer. I have to source `ftplugin/txt.vim` each time a buffer is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blows into the same horn as @PeterRincker's answer, but I think you should follow [`:help new-filetype-scripts`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype-scripts), as the description (*if your filetype can only be detected by inspecting the contents of the file*) matches your use case perfectly.

With that, you put the following contents into `~/.vim/scripts.vim`:

```
if did_filetype()   " filetype already set..
    finish      " ..don't do these checks
endif
if getline(1) =~ '^title:'
    setfiletype markdown
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `:h new-filetype` part B you can do something like the following:

```
augroup txt_to_markdown
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead * if &filetype == 'text && getline(1) =~ '^title:' | set filetype=markdown | endif
augroup END
```